# Writing excel formulas on pandas DataFrame that depends on Row/Column values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have the following df:

```
     Column1  Column2
0    19843    30
1    19842    35
2    19841    40
3    19840    45
4    19839    50
5    19838    55
```

I need to generate a third column that depends of Column1, Column2 and row numbem, like de following:

```
column3_formula = '"={row_number}*(Column1 + Column2)"'
```

I Know that this is kinda weird but Im trying to abstract and simplify my real problem ( my Df has more than 50 columns and I need to add 30 more columns that are Excel formulas ).
I already have a way to "parse" the DF Column Names to "Excel real columns" (A3, or C2...):

```
def excel_column(column_number):
    letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    quot, rem = divmod(column_number - 1, len(letters))
    return (
        excel_column(quot) + chr(rem + ord('A')) if column_number != 0 else ''
    )

attributes_excel_column_mapping = {
    v: excel_column(k) for k, v in enumerate(['Column1', 'Column2'], 1)
}
```

With this structure I can do things like `column3_formula.format(**attributes_excel_column_mapping)` but how can I feel the row number to insert this formulas like `my_df['Column3] = ...` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what Excel has to do with this, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC My output will be a csv with excel formulas.
Therefore, some columns in my DF must be strings with excel syntax.
The function `attributes_excel_column_mapping` maps the columns of my df to me and returns them to me with the names of the excel columns (A1, B6 etc ...), I just can't map" the number of the line I'm on ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was the "name" attribute of row when I use the apply method.
Example:

```
            self.data_frame['column'] = self.data_frame.apply(
                lambda row: formula.format(
                    **column_mapping, row_number=row.name
                ),
                axis=1
            )
```

where formula is a string like

```
formula = "=IFERROR({column1}{row_number}>0;1 ..... )"
and
```

column_mapping = {
            v: excel_column(k) for k, v in enumerate(ordered_attributes, 1)
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
my_df['Column3']=my_df.index*(my_df['Column1']+my_df['Column2'])
```

Comment: Column 3 must be a string with the formula mentioned and not the account itself.